# Why is this method not being called properly?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am learning react with typescript and i have the following problem:

App.tsx

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import Header from './components/Header';
import Tasks from './components/Tasks';
import { TaskType } from './components/Task'

function App() {

  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState<TaskType[]>([
    {
        id: 0,
        text: 'Doctors Appointment',
        day: 'Feb 4th at 2:30 pm',
        reminder: true
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        text: 'Meeting at school',
        day: 'Feb 5th at 3:50 pm',
        reminder: true
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        text: 'food shopping',
        day: 'Feb 4th at 2:30 pm',
        reminder: false
    }
  ]);

  const deleteTask = (id: number) => {
    console.log('Delete', id);
  }

  // Delete task function
  const someTitle = 'Title';

  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <Header title={someTitle}></Header>
      <Tasks tasks={tasks} onDelete={() => deleteTask}></Tasks>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The method deleteTask() is not getting called from the inner components below: (Tasks are a list of Task)

Tasks.tsx

```
import Task from './Task'
import { TaskType } from './Task'

export interface ITasksListProps {
    tasks: TaskType[]
    onDelete: React.MouseEventHandler
}

const Tasks: React.FC<ITasksListProps> = ({tasks, onDelete}) => {

    return (
        <>
        {tasks.map ((task) => (
            <Task key={task.id} task={task} onDelete={() => onDelete}/>
        ))}
        </>
    )
}

export default Tasks
```

Task.tsx

```
import { FaTimes } from 'react-icons/fa'

export type TaskType = {
    id: number,
    text: string,
    day: string,
    reminder: boolean
}

export interface ITaskProps {
    task: TaskType
    onDelete: React.MouseEventHandler
}

const Task = ({task, onDelete}: ITaskProps) => {
    return (
        <div className='task'>  
            <h3>{task.text} <FaTimes style={{ color: 'red', cursor: 'pointer' }} onClick={onDelete} /></h3>
            <p>{task.day}</p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Task
```

Where is the error here? I can't figure out how to retain those states and simultaneously get the method to be called properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the updated files, even "onDelete" removes your tasks.
Let me know if it worked or not.
[Codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-christian-njh921?file=/src/App.tsx)

```js
// App.tsx
import { useState } from "react";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Tasks from "./components/Tasks";
import { TaskType } from "./components/Task";

function App() {
  const defaultState = [
    {
      id: 0,
      text: "Doctors Appointment",
      day: "Feb 4th at 2:30 pm",
      reminder: true
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      text: "Meeting at school",
      day: "Feb 5th at 3:50 pm",
      reminder: true
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      text: "food shopping",
      day: "Feb 4th at 2:30 pm",
      reminder: false
    }
  ];

  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState<TaskType[]>(defaultState);

  const deleteTask = (id: number) => {
    console.log("id is", id);
    const filteredTasks = tasks.filter((each) => each.id !== id);
    setTasks(filteredTasks);
  };

  // Delete task function
  const someTitle = "Title";

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Header title={someTitle}></Header>
      <Tasks {...{ tasks, onDelete: deleteTask }}></Tasks>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```js
// Header.tsx
export default function Header(props: { title: string }) {
  const { title } = props;
  return <div>Header {title}</div>;
}
```

```js
// Task.tsx
import { FaTimes } from "react-icons/fa";

export type TaskType = {
  id: number;
  text: string;
  day: string;
  reminder: boolean;
};

export interface ITaskProps {
  task: TaskType;
  onDelete: Function;
}

const Task = ({ task, onDelete }: ITaskProps) => {
  return (
    <div className="task">
      <h3>
        {task.text}{" "}
        <FaTimes
          style={{ color: "red", cursor: "pointer" }}
          onClick={() => onDelete(task.id)}
        />
      </h3>
      <p>{task.day}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Task;
```

```js
// Tasks.tsx

import React from "react";
import Task from "./Task";
import { TaskType } from "./Task";

export interface ITasksListProps {
  tasks: TaskType[];
  onDelete: Function;
}

const Tasks: React.FC<ITasksListProps> = ({ tasks, onDelete }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {tasks.map((task) => (
        <Task key={task.id} {...{ task, onDelete }} />
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

export default Tasks;
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I have some questions to follow this up with though:
Does separating the task as a type in this case a correct approach? (I'm asking about the implementation i provided, and for any best practices that would be better)
Is defining onDelete simply as Function enough? Isn't this approach too generic? (asking from best practices point of view)
Could you elaborate a bit on this:
Task.tsx
{. . .{ task, onDelete} } />
What are those 3 dots used for?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `...` is known as a spread operator. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: @MTomys <Component name={name} age={"12"} prof={"js"} /> if your component has a lot of props to be passed, quickly you see it gets clogged up. So writing like this,
<Component {...{name, age: "12", prof: "js"}}/> is just a compact way of writing the same thing!

Comment: Here  I would say, there was no need to pass onDelete function, you could have just passed setState, and destructured in Tasks.tsx, and renamed as setParentState
const {setState: setParentState} = props; You could have just written "Task" component inside Tasks.tsx ... These are the only changes I am thiking of to make the project more compact. Only study about "props drilling"

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using it wrong

```
 <Tasks tasks={tasks} onDelete={() => deleteTask}></Tasks>
```

Here you should do for example

```
<Tasks tasks={tasks} onDelete={() => deleteTask(5)}></Tasks>
```

So what is happening is that

```
onClick={onDelete}
```

basically means that `onClick = onDelete` but

```
onDelete={() => deleteTask}
```

means `onDelete = () => { deleteTask }` you are just referencing the method but not invoking it.

Comment: Unfortunately putting in some number as a parameter does not work, and if i try to pass the text.id in Task (onDelete(task.id)) i get "Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MouseEvent<Element, MouseEvent>'.ts(2345)"

Comment: Try setting `onDelete` type to correct type. Ex. `onDelete: (id: number) => void`. onClick has a internal mouseEventType but your onDelete does not corresbond to the type of mouse event. so just replace it with `onClick={() => onDelete(task.id)}`